# PerformanceProgressBar WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, progress-bar

For a windows Phone app data is loaded async from Web Api's.
While the data is loading something must indicate it. 
I found something about a progress bar but it don't show up:

```
<toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Yellow" Foreground="Purple" IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="Visible"></toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar>
```

Does anyone know a good example or way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the integrated shell:systemtray.progressindicator for this!
A list of examples can be found [here...](http://nik.rolls.cc/2012/03/06/windows-phone-system-tray-tricks/)

Answer (score 3):

PerformanceProgressBar is removed from wp8 version of Phone toolkit, since the built-in ProgressBar does not have performance issues, check [this out](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/9270c3db-3e30-4bdf-be83-ea508853030c)

However, your code should still for WP 7.1